# MacOS Catalina, Java, Multicast not Working

Tags: java, macos, multicast

I have two iMacs sitting together on the same network.  One is older and running Mojave the other is new and running Catalina.  Both are using Java 8 and both are listening to the same multicast channels.  The old one receives the multicasts fine, the new one does not.

tcpdump shows that the packets are being received on the new machine but the java multicast listener is not showing them.

Here is the java multicast listener code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MulticastListenerBare {

    public MulticastListenerBare(String ip, int port) {
    try {
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        MulticastSocket sin = new MulticastSocket(port);
        sin.joinGroup(group);
        byte[] buf = new byte[64*1024];
        DatagramPacket pin = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,
                            group, port);
        System.out.printf("Listening to %s : %d\n", ip, port);
        while (true) {
        sin.receive(pin);
        String data = new String(buf, 0, pin.getLength());
        System.out.println("Received: \n" + data);
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Unknown Throwable happened: " + t.getMessage());
    }
    }//constructor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println
        ("usage: java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true " +
         "MulticastListener ip port\n");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    try {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        new MulticastListenerBare(args[0], port);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("error parsing port #: '" + args[1] + "'");
    }
    }//main
}//MulticastListenerBare
```

Under Catalina's system preferences 'Security & Privacy', I have granted full disk access to both java and terminal.

The program is run from the terminal like this:

`java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true MulticastListenerBare 239.192.2.25 52025`

Any ideas as to why it is not picking up the multicasts?

Comment: I got this to work using the latest version of Java (15).  It does not work using Java 8 or 11.  So now the question is what does Catalina not like about Multicast in earlier versions of Java?

Comment: One thing to look out for is which network interface (NIC) the `MulticastSocket` joins. It's left unspecified in the code and default selection might differ between JVM versions. There is an overloaded version of `joinGroup()` that takes a `NetworkInterface` parameter that should help the implementation be more explicit. It should definitely work under Java 8 and 11.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I tried it and it still does not work.  It definitely does work in Java 8 & 11 with older versions of MacOS just not with MacOS Catalina.